# How to efficiently get the row nr for each column where condition is met in a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Following this earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019576/transform-matrix) about a numpy matrix transformation.

```
np_array = np.matrix(
   [[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]]
)
```

What would be the most efficient way of getting the row nr for each column where there is 1 without looping? If a column has no row with number 1 in it should return np.nan for that column.
The result if this numpy matrix would be a

```
np.array([7,5,3,1,0,1,3,5,7,5,5])
```

Comment: `np_array.argmax(0)` as used in the accepted answer to previous question?

Comment: thank you :) i think that question is then not necessary and can be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i,j=np.where(np_array==1)
```

where i is list of indexes identifying the row and j is list of indexes denoting the column